# Having trouble resolving components in owned scope with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Here's my code sample:

```
class Item
{
    public Item(IFoo foo)
    {
        // Expected useful foo but got fake foo
    }
}

interface IFoo
{
}

class FakeFoo : IFoo
{
}

class UsefulFoo : IFoo
{
    Func<Item> _itemFactory;

    public UsefulFoo(Func<Item> itemFactory)
    {
        _itemFactory = itemFactory;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _itemFactory();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Item>().AsSelf();

        builder.RegisterType<UsefulFoo>().As<IFoo>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .OnActivated( x => x.Instance.Initialize());
        builder.RegisterType<FakeFoo>().As<IFoo>().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
        // Fake foo
        var fakeFoo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
        // Owned<usefulfoo>
        var scoped = container.Resolve<Owned<UsefulFoo>>();
    }
}
```

I expect that `Func<Item>` which is resolved in `Owned<UsefulFoo>` scope will put `UsefulFoo` to Item constructor ( because it's owned scope, isn't it? ).
But actually in Item constructor I have FakeFoo. Why?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have two `IFoo` implementation: `FakeFoo` for global scope and `UsefulFoo` for owned scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Autofac, the rule is "last one in wins."

If you register more than one component that exposes a service, the last one you register will be the one that gets resolved. In this case, you register `FakeFoo` *after* `UsefulFoo`. When you resolve the `Owned<T>` object, you're specifically resolving a `UsefulFoo` - but when you resolve `Item`, it takes an `IFoo`... and the last `IFoo` implementation registered was `FakeFoo`.

If you need `UsefulFoo` to be the default implementation of `IFoo`, register it last.